how to draw an arc with fabric.js pencil brush?
I want to use pencil brush of fabric.js to make a tool to let user can draw an arc by dragging and dropping.
I make a function：
   public static setArcBrush(canvas: fabric.Canvas, cellWidth: number) { 
     const ArcBrush = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.PencilBrush, { 
       type: 'ArcBrush', 
       width:  cellWidth / 2,
       initialize: function () {
            this.callSuper('initialize', canvas);
       },

    onMouseDown: function (pointer: fabric.Point, options: fabric.IEvent<MouseEvent>) {
        this.started = true;
        this.startX = pointer.x;
        this.startY = pointer.y;
        this.endX = pointer.x;
        this.endY = pointer.y;
        this.arc = new fabric.Path('M 0 0', {
            stroke: this.color,
            strokeWidth: this.width,
            fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            selectable: true,
            objectCaching: false,
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
        });
        this.canvas.add(this.arc);
    },

    onMouseMove: function (pointer: fabric.Point, options: fabric.IEvent<MouseEvent>) {
        if (!this.started) return;

        this.endX = pointer.x;
        this.endY = pointer.y;
        const radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.endX - this.startX, 2) + Math.pow(this.endY - this.startY, 2)) / 2;
        const centerX = (this.startX + this.endX) / 2;
        const centerY = (this.startY + this.endY) / 2;

        const startAngle = Math.atan2(this.startY - centerY, this.startX - centerX);
        const endAngle = Math.atan2(this.endY - centerY, this.endX - centerX);

        const largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= Math.PI ? "0" : "1";

        const pathData = [
            `M ${this.startX} ${this.startY}`,
            `A ${radius} ${radius} 0 ${largeArcFlag} 1 ${this.endX} ${this.endY}`
        ].join(' ');

        this.arc.set({ path: pathData });
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    },

    onMouseUp: function (pointer: fabric.Point, options: fabric.IEvent<MouseEvent>) {
        if (this.started) {
            this.started = false;
            this.arc.setCoords();
        }
    },
});

canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new ArcBrush();
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
} 

I use this function to draw an arc on a canvas, but the arc is invisible while I can use canvas.getObjects() to print the arc objects. I do not know why I can not see the arc.
